# getting error like ur view controller and nib file

Tags: iphone

i have observed 1 warning when i am opening my nib file ,but that doesnt effected my out put ..
i want to to know what causes this error
its showing ' View Controller' has both its 'View' and 'NIB Name' properties set. This configuration is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if your viewcontroller object on your MainWindow.xib has child views, mainly a UIView, in that xib AND has the "NIB Name" property set to some existing XIB.

you can either move the child views from the viewcontroller object in the MainWindow.xib to the viewcontrollers actual xib file via copy and paste.

or you can clear out that NIB Name variable found on the first inspector pane of the viewcontroler object in the MainWindow.xib